# ionic - app runs on Android 6 but no android 5.1

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an app with ionic framework, it runs fine on the browser and on my phone, which is android 6.0.1. However after installing it on another phone with android 5.1.1 it displays the splash screen, then it fades and show a blank screen.

What can be the cause of this? In my config.xml I hae the following :

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
```

Please let me know if I should provide more information.

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using?

Comment: Do you have 5.1.1 in your Android SDK ?

Comment: I've managed to fix it by upgrading the phone os, it still shows as 5.1.1 but I think it applied bugfixes :), so I don't think it was related to ionic.